# TypeError: $('#calendar').fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to use Full Calendar 3.1.0 and am getting the following error. I am wondering if Full Calendar is not compatible with jQuery 2.2.4?

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Many thanks,

John

Comment: You may have placed the files on the wrong place and tried to activate `.fullCalendar()` before the file(s) are loaded

Comment: @C0dekid - Thanks, as simple as that! All working now.

Comment: You're welcome ^^ :)